# The return value of "orElseThrow" must be used

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

When I am scanning code with sonar lint the following code shows the bug as "The return value of "orElseThrow" must be used"

```
itemList.stream()
    .filter(item -> orderItemId.equals(item.getId()))
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("12345","Item Not Found"));
```

This is just for a validation purpose no need to return anything from this statement. need to validate whether the item exists or not.

FYI: Eclipse showing a quick fix as squid:S2201

Anybody have any idea how to resolve this bug?

Comment: Thank you @ Aominè  for the solution. <code> if(itemList.stream().noneMatch(i->orderItemId.equals(i.getId()))){ 
 throw new BadRequestException("12345","Item Not Found"); 
}

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a warning (not using the value returned by `orElseThrow()` shouldn't be an error).

If you wish to eliminate that warning, use `isPresent()` instead:

```
if (!itemList.stream().filter(i->orderItemId.equals(i.getId())).findAny().isPresent()) {
    throw new BadRequestException("12345","Item Not Found");
}
```

or just avoid using `Optional`s, and use `anyMatch()` instead:

```
if (!itemList.stream().anyMatch(i->orderItemId.equals(i.getId()))) {
    throw new BadRequestException("12345","Item Not Found");
}
```

Comment: Using empty() seems not the correct way.How ever the second option anyMatch() is the perfect solution for this.Thank you.

Comment: for the first solution, I believe you're looking for `!itemList.stream().filter(i->orderItemId.equals(i.getId())).findAny().isPresent()` but the better solution would be to use `itemList.stream().noneMatch(i->orderItemId.equals(i.getId()))`

Comment: @Aominè yep, for some reason I was sure there was an `empty()` method that indicates whether an existing Optional is empty.

Comment: …and eliminate the *logical not* by using `noneMatch` in the first place.

Comment: My opinion is that this is not a solution changing your code with a simply `orElseThrow` to something else only because a false positive warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the sonar, there is an open ticket to resolve this issue (https://community.sonarsource.com/t/fp-java-s2201-optional-orelsethrow-return-value-must-be-used/85204), the best thing to do until it is resolved is to just ignore this rule